# How to call a non-static method from a non-static class using method reference in Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, method-reference

I have the following class:

```
class Book {
    private String genre;
    public Book(String genre) {this.genre = genre;}
    public String getGenre() {return genre;}
    public class BookFilter {
        public boolean isFiction(Book b) {
            return b.getGenre().equals("fiction");
        }
    }
}
```

I have added to `books` list a few objects of `Book` class and now I want to filter the stream using method reference. As it is shown in the below code, using `lambda expression` the code works fine but using `method reference`, it does not compile.

```
books.stream()
    .filter(b->b.new BookFilter().isFiction(b)) //Works fine
    //.filter(new Book().new BookFilter()::isFiction); //Will not compile
```

I know that if the `BookFilter` was a `static nested class`, the following line of code would pass compilation without any problem.

```
.filter(new Book.BookFilter()::isFiction)
```

How do I call `isFiction()` method from `Book` class using method reference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there any reason why you are not using `.filter(b -> b.getGenre().equals("fiction"))` directly?

Comment: @AlexisC. I am using it but I wanted to know if the same thing can be achieved using method reference.

Comment: Ok, by the way you may make your inner `BookFilter` class static, as there is no reason for it to be tied to a particular instance book given that you already give it as parameter to your `isFiction` function (given the usage of it in your `Stream#filter` method).

Comment: @AlexisC. Many thanks because now I have a very good understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason your remarked `filter` call doesn't pass compilation is that your `Book` class has no parameter-less constructor.

If you add to it

```
public Book() {}
```

then

```
books.stream().filter(new Book().new BookFilter()::isFiction);
```

will pass compilation.